# Rsync via crontab doesn't work

Tags: backup, cron, rsync

I want to run a `rsync` in a cron job.

The `rsync` task is :

```
rsync -avz -e "ssh -i /home/mypc/.ssh/bkpRsync" --delete /home/mypc/backup/ root@vpsxxxxx.ovh.net:backup/
```

It works, when done manually.
But the cron line:

```
0 */2 * * * rsync -avz -e "ssh -i /home/mypc/.ssh/bkpRsync" --delete home/mypc/backup/ root@vpsxxxxx.ovh.net:backup/
```

doesn't perform any transfer to the vps.
I do have a log that tells that the rsync has been performed though.
I have tried creating the crontab with sudo, thinking that it was a right issue. It didn't help.
I don't understand why the cron task doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

You're missing the leading slash from your home directory in the crontab command, so you're syncing across to a location that doesn't exist already. You should check whether you've created a backup in `/root/home/mypc/backup/` on the VPS which you will probably wish to delete.

Change

```
0 */2 * * * rsync -avz -e "ssh -i /home/mypc/.ssh/bkpRsync" --delete home/mypc/backup/ root@vpsxxxxx.ovh.net:backup/
```

to

```
0 */2 * * * rsync -avz -e "ssh -i /home/mypc/.ssh/bkpRsync" --delete /home/mypc/backup/ root@vpsxxxxx.ovh.net:backup/
```